# Adding Bulk Users to Visual Studio Team Service (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add close to 100 users to Azure DevOps (Visual Studio Team Service). Since adding them individually is quite a cumbersome task, is there any way by which a bulk users can be added at one go?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback the idea.
But for now, the feature is not available for Azure DevOps.

And I posted the link [Add the feature to bulk add users to an Azure DevOps organization](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/336642/add-the-feature-to-bulk-add-users-to-an-azure-devo.html) to suggest the feature, you can follow up there.